# Why the two implementations of random sort vary a lot in performance?

Tags: java, sorting, random

I need to implement a random sort, which is very bad at performance but just used to get used to random generating things:

I have two implementations:

```
public void sort(Integer[] a) {
    boolean sorted = false;
    boolean auxSorted = true;
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a);
    int n = a.length;

    while (sorted == false) {
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < n-1 && list.get(i) <= list.get(i + 1)) {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (i == n - 1) {
            sorted = true;
        }
    Integer[] sortedArray = new Integer[list.size()];
    a = list.toArray(sortedArray);
}
```

when I use an array of length 5 it gives correct answer very quickly,
however I have another for loop version:

```
while (sorted == false) {
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            if(list.get(i) > list.get(i+1)) {
                auxSorted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(auxSorted) {
            sorted = true;              
        }

    }
```

when I test with the same array it runs extremely slowly.

Are there any differences between the two implementations? To me I think the for loop version is actually more efficient in this context.

Comment: You could start by posting code that has matching braces.

Comment: If you set `auxSorted = false`, you never set it back to `true`.

Comment: Why is there a loop at all?? `Collections.shuffle(list)` is all you need. P.S. **never compare a `boolean` value to `true` or `false`**.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No, the OP is actually using shuffle to sort. Keep shuffling until the array happens to be in order. I'm not sure what the point of this is.

Comment: @PaulBoddington ah, what well known `O(n!)` sorting algorithm. Maybe `Collections.sort` might be a little more performant...

Answer (score 0):

In the second one you never set `auxSorted` to true, so you are never able to make `sorted` true. This means your loop runs infinitely. Which is very slow indeed.

```
while (!sorted) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    auxSorted = true; //You need this

    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if(list.get(i) > list.get(i+1)) {
            auxSorted = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(auxSorted) {
        sorted = true;              
    }
}
```

You are correct that the 2nd implementation is more efficient than the first, but the question remains as to why you'd ever want to do this when you randomly generate something or sort something. As it's a terribly inefficient way to do either.

Comment: I'm not even sure the second implementation is more efficient.

Comment: @biziclop I think it is, but only because OP doesn't create new Lists and Arrays each loop.

Comment: Interesting point raised, not sure what are some real application of random short. Wiki Pedia link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort